# Store a variable in a txt file or xml file

Tags: php, javascript, xml, forms

I do not have access to a database. Is there a way to store a php or javascript in a permanent txt file or xml file?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You might want to use SQLlite, it ships with php and uses a file; but exactly what do you want to do? usually you don't store php in database anyway

Comment: i have a simple php form with a built in wysiwyg editor. it sends the data with BR tags and such to a page. I want that data to be displayed on a Outlook HTML Signiture which only uses javascript

Comment: `I want that data to be displayed on a Outlook HTML Signiture which only uses javascript` - you can do that at all, no matter how much you might want to. Outlook will not let you send or receive raw (plain text) Javascript source code in any form, and strips it out of the message. It is very very very annoying - if you want to send anyone any Javascript you have to zip it up or otherwise encode it, and there is no way anything will let you execute Javascript in the context of an email. I wasted a good half a day trying to send someone a JS calculator once, and it can't be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Direct answer to the question

To answer your question directly (storing one variable) you would do:

```
$file_path = '/path/to/your/text.file';
$my_var = 'my value';
file_put_contents($file_path, serialize($my_var));
```

To retrieve the value you would do something like this:

```
$my_var = '';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($file_path);
if(!empty($file_contents)) {
    $my_var = unserialize($file_contents);
}
```

By using [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) you allow your code to store an array or stdClass object as well as numbers and strings in `$my_var`.

### SQLite would be better

If the server supports [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) then I would recommend using it if you need to store more than one variable.

To interact with SQLite I would recommend using PHPs [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or perhaps [Idiorm](http://j4mie.org/blog/idiorm-a-simple-orm-for-php/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't store files with JavaScript. However you can easily write files (on the server) with PHP. If you would like to store a simple plain text to a file simply do this:

```
File_Put_Contents ( '/path/to/file.txt', 'some content' );
```

If you would like to manipulate XML, take a look at the [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/simplexml) extension.

You could also use [SQLite](http://www.php.net/sqlite) for your database, as it is "just" a file and you don't have to install anything (PHP>=5).

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least FTP access you need to create writable folder(i.e. set permissions to 777). From your PHP code:

```
$data = 'some data'; //xml or txt or whatever
file_put_contents('path_to_your_writable_folder/your_file_name.txt', $data);
```

Comment: How would I store or covert my javascript variable to use php?

Comment: If you are going to use PHP variable data in JS you need to encode PHP array/object with json_encode($your_php_array); and put it in file. Later this file can be loaded in document with script src="path/to/your/file.js" etc...

Answer (score 0):

Write it to a file, take a look at [Flintstone](http://www.xeweb.net/flintstone/) a key/value database store using flat files.